# Beginner Angularjs UI Routing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have began learning AngularJS and decided to go with Angular-UI-Router for all of my routing needs, but unfortunately, I am unable to get the templateURL property of the $stateProvider to render. I have followed tutorials to the world's end, and cannot get templateURL to work (even when following the tutorial). Am I missing something?

All of the following documents are located within the same directory. I am opening the webpage directly in Chrome (I am not combining with node/express or any other service).

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">

<nav>
<a ui-sref="home">Home</a>
<a ui-sref="about">About</a>
</nav>

<div ui-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']).

config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider

        .state('home', {url: '/home', template: '<h1>HOME</h1>'})
        .state('about', {url: '/about', templateURL: 'about.html'});

}]);
```

**about.html**

```
<div><p>About</p></div>
```

Comment: Pretty sure the property name is `templateUrl` (case sensitive)

Comment: This is the correct answer and I would vote on it if it was posted that way. Javascript is case-sensitive.

Comment: Changed templateURL to templateUrl

Comment: If you're opening the page "directly in chrome" it sounds like you're opening it via the `file://` protocol. Angular will try to fetch the template via `http://` and that won't work due to browser security settings. Try setting up a webserver.

Comment: @ChadRobinson Just vote to close as a *typo*.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Here is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GWkdBN1aMmJTy9FTViMk?p=preview) you can use for testing.

The documentation for:

### [$stateProvider.state(stateName, stateConfig)](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stateprovider-1) (cite)

#### template, templateUrl, templateProvider

> Three ways to set up your templates. Only use one per state (or view, see below)!
>
> - **`template`** String HTML content, or function that returns an HTML string
> - **`templateUrl`** String URL path to template file OR Function, returns URL path string
> - **`templateProvider`** Function, returns HTML content string

So, this is the updated state def:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {url: '/home', template: '<h1>HOME</h1>'})
    .state('about', {url: '/about', templateUrl: 'about.html'});
```

Also, we can use the $urlRouterProvider.otherwise() to init some existing state:

```
// no state iwth url:'/' at the moment
// $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
// init ui-router's existing state on "unknown" url
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

Try to obaserve it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/GWkdBN1aMmJTy9FTViMk?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it was a simple typo. Have to remember that javascript is case sensitive.